Unable to Share Spatial Anchors in a Multi-User App Using PUN2
I am currently developing an application for Meta Quest 3 that utilizes multi-user passthrough functionality. Based on the following reference article, I have successfully implemented spatial anchor placement.
Reference Article: Quest Spatial Anchor - Zenn
However, the next step is to make the app multi-user by using Photon Unity Networking 2 (PUN2). Specifically, I want to share and synchronize the placed spatial anchors among multiple users, but I'm unsure how to implement this.
Current Situation:

Spatial anchor placement works correctly in a local environment.
Basic setup of PUN2 is complete, but I don't know how to share the anchors.

Question:
How can I implement PUN2 to share and synchronize spatial anchors in a multi-user environment? Any specific code examples or best practices would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Information:

Unity Version: 2022.3
PUN2 Version: Latest
Plugins and SDKs related to spatial anchors: Using Meta XR All-in-one SDK


You can use custom properties from PUN2 to share your anchor.
When you have successfully created a new anchor, you can save it on the cloud to use it later. It will return an anchor uuid (Guid).
More information on this doc from Meta : https://developers.meta.com/horizon/documentation/unity/unity-spatial-anchors-persist-content/
Then you can save this uuid as a string in your Photon room with something like that :
    string uuid = anchor.Uuid.ToString();
    
    Hashtable propsToSet = new()
    {
        { _ACTIVE_ANCHOR, uuid }
    };

    PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.SetCustomProperties(propsToSet);

The other user can retrieve this uuid :
    string uuidToConvert;

    uuidToConvert = (string)PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.CustomProperties[_ACTIVE_ANCHOR];

    Guid anchorID = new Guid(uuidToConvert);

Then you can use the method from Meta to load an anchor with this Guid.
You will have to load, localize, then bind the new anchor.
Note : You need to use the hashtable from Photon with :
using Hashtable = ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable;

I hope I've been able to answer your question
